# Spring Boot + ReactiveCosmosRepository + java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.util.concurrent.Queues.empty()Ljava/util/function/Supplier

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am implementing Cosmos DB in my Spring Boot project, and am getting error while connecting to Azure Cosmos DB.

POM.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-cosmosdb</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
<version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Repository

```
package com.staples.ctg.repository.cosmos;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.repository.ReactiveCosmosRepository;
import com.staples.ctg.service.dto.cache.GenericCacheDTO;


@Repository
public interface SpotCacheRepository extends  ReactiveCosmosRepository <GenericCacheDTO, String> {

}
```

applicationProperties.yml

```
azure:        

cosmosdb:

    uri: Cosmos URI

    key: Key

    database: DB Name that I created
```

DTO

```
package com.staples.ctg.service.dto.cache;

@Document(collection="cosmos")
public class GenericCacheDTO {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @PartitionKey
    private String accountId;

}
```

When I spin up locally, I am getting below error

```
2020-02-14 12:20:32.922  INFO 22777 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [<Azure Cosmos URI>], connectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy{requestTimeoutInMillis=60000, mediaRequestTimeoutInMillis=300000, connectionMode=DIRECT, maxPoolSize=1000, idleConnectionTimeoutInMillis=60000, userAgentSuffix=';spring-data/2.2.0;8d0607104487ba8c93ae7a32c5e20645d1bb21edf269625ead71da72d4877d65;', retryOptions=RetryOptions{maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=9, maxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds=30}, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=null, usingMultipleWriteLocations=false, inetSocketProxyAddress=null}], consistencyLevel [null], directModeProtocol [Tcp]
2020-02-14 12:20:32.922 DEBUG 22777 --- [  restartedMain] reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory       : Using Slf4j logging framework
2020-02-14 12:20:32.979 DEBUG 22777 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.d.c.internal.GlobalEndpointManager   : registering a refresh in [300000] ms
2020-02-14 12:20:33.034 DEBUG 22777 --- [     parallel-1] c.a.d.c.internal.GlobalEndpointManager   : startRefreshLocationTimerAsync() - Invoking refresh, I was registered on [2020-02-14T12:20:32.985]
2020-02-14 12:20:33.035  INFO 22777 --- [     parallel-1] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Getting database account endpoint from https:<Azure Cosmos URI>
2020-02-14 12:20:33.123 DEBUG 22777 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=8, workerCount=8}
2020-02-14 12:20:33.123 DEBUG 22777 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: PooledConnectionProvider {name=http, poolFactory=reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$$Lambda$2068/965477132@65222f44}
2020-02-14 12:20:33.130 DEBUG 22777 --- [     parallel-1] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll       : Default Epoll support : false
2020-02-14 12:20:33.132 DEBUG 22777 --- [     parallel-1] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue      : Default KQueue support : false
2020-02-14 12:20:33.162 DEBUG 22777 --- [     parallel-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : Creating new client pool [reactor-netty-connection-pool] for <Azure Cosmos URI>
2020-02-14 12:20:33.183 ERROR 22777 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers        : Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.util.concurrent.Queues.empty()Ljava/util/function/Supplier;
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleFifoPool.<clinit>(SimpleFifoPool.java:35)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolBuilder.build(PoolBuilder.java:333)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolBuilder.fifo(PoolBuilder.java:321)
    at reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider.lambda$fixed$3(ConnectionProvider.java:197)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator.<init>(PooledConnectionProvider.java:237)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.lambda$acquire$2(PooledConnectionProvider.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.lambda$acquire$3(PooledConnectionProvider.java:148)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:54)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:319)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3088)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.resubscribe(FluxRetryPredicate.java:123)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryPredicate.subscribe(MonoRetryPredicate.java:51)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:322)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle.subscribe(MonoSingle.java:58)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSourceMono.subscribe(FluxSourceMono.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle.subscribe(MonoSingle.java:58)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3088)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribe(MonoRetryWhen.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSourceMono.subscribe(FluxSourceMono.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume.subscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek.subscribe(FluxPeek.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek.subscribe(FluxPeek.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek.subscribe(FluxPeek.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle.subscribe(MonoSingle.java:58)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-02-14 12:20:46.801  WARN 22777 --- [scoveryClient-1] c.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask  : task supervisor timed out

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
```

Comment: Are you able to build `mvn install`

Comment: I generally run in debug mode from STS. The error I pasted is from STS IDE Console. I just tried 'mvn install' from Terminal, and I got different error and that sounds very strange as I do have those in application-local.yml file .***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************Description:
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'azure.cosmosdb' to com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.cosmosdb.CosmosDBProperties failed:

Comment: Property: azure.cosmosdb.key
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty
    Property: azure.cosmosdb.database
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty
    Property: azure.cosmosdb.uri
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty
Action:
Update your application's configuration

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a reactor-core incorrect version issue.

This dependency might be bringing an older version of reactor-core.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Two ways to solve this issue:

1. Try excluding reactor-core from this dependency.
2. Try adding reactor-core dependency - 3.3.0 or higher.

Comment: Thank you Kushagra for your response. With updated version, the error that I was getting was gone, but getting a different error while generating classes in target folder. My application was generated with jHipster, so am not sure if Jhipster is compatible with Cosmos DB SQL API. Jhipster website (https://www.jhipster.tech/azure/#nosql-databases)  doesn't talk anything about Cosmos DB SQL API, so unsure if it is compatible. Appreciate if any thoughts on this .